# Apply changes made on branch to trunk

Tags: svn, branch, trunk

I'm currently working on a web application development. Our company methodology is to work on the project trunk for as long as possible and switch to the branches only when necessary.

However, in order to guarantee the success of a recent deploy, I have worked directly on the client specific branch. I would like to know how can I apply the made changes to the trunk?

Comment: @rugioncalves - You may get more responses to your questions if you accept the answers (if they do indeed answer your question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[svn merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re16.html)

Specifically, it sounds like you want to use:

```
svn merge -r N:M SOURCE [PATH]
```